# How to search and extract in a dataframe in #R using a pattern that includes moving from columns and rows?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I would like to search and extract from a big dataframe in R a number that is located in different places but is always located one column and one row more than the word "LAYER".

I have tried to do it but I can only find a way to extract "LAYER" with a `filter` using the `dplyr` package but maybe I need to use something different.

For example, in the following table I would like to extract the **2** and the **3.65** that are **bold** in the dataframe.

| X1 | X2 | X3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LAYER | 1 | NA |
| 190 | **2** | NA |
| NA | 20 | 1200 |
| NA | 30 | 2200 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| LAYER | 2 | NA |
| 180 | **3.65** | NA |
| NA | 50 | 1850 |
| NA | 95 | 2300 |
| ... | ... | ... |

To obtain an output like this

| X |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3.65 |
| ... |

Thank you very much in advance,

A desperate R beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the indices where `X1` is `'LAYER'` and extract next `X2` value.

```
inds <- which(data$X1 == 'LAYER')
result <- data.frame(X2 = data$X2[inds + 1])
```